# How to calculate average items, received from trapper, in zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

For example, I get value with key "myTag.some_total_time" by zabbix trapper. I want to see on graph average time of all values for last 5 minute. I know that there are "calculated items" and aggregate functions, but it can not be used with trapper values?

Comment: Thank you for this question but this is probably more related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated values can be used with trappers. To do this, you create a calculated element for the element you need.

Ex:

```
avg(//your_trap_item,5m)
```

Comment: do I need create new item (in addition trapper item) with type "calculated" and any key, and set in formula this expression? 
I see error: `Invalid parameter "/1/params": incorrect expression starting from "avg(/myTag.some_total_time,5m)". 

I tried "//myTag.some_total_time", "/host/myTag.some_total_time". 
But i don't see data on graph

Comment: It's works! Thanks